# don't understand this iterative approach to finding a subsequence between 2 strings

Tags: javascript, algorithm, pointers, sequence

This is the question:

> Write a function called `isSubsequence` which takes in two strings and checks whether the characters in the first string form a subsequence of the characters in the second string. In other words, the function should check whether the characters in the first string appear somewhere in the second string, **without their order changing**.

I have the solution below but there are a few parts I don't get :

1. Why the need for: `if (!str1) return true;`
2. I don't get this line either: `if (i===str1.length) return true;`

Will appreciate any explanations thanks!

```
function isSubsequence(str1, str2) {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  if (!str1) return true;
  while (j < str2.length) {
    if (str2[j] === str1[i]) i++;
    if (i === str1.length) return true;
    j++;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: 1: if `str1` is falsy (=empty), there is nothing to check. 2: `i` holds the current place of `str1`. Once it equals the length of `str1` it was fully checked. `str2` could be longer than `str1`. **Sidenote:** I would prefer to get `false` returned on 1 or have it renamed to `isSubsequenceOrEmpty`. Also be aware to stringify the parameters before checking.

Comment: I have never been a fan of those multiple `return` structures.

Comment: @JavaScript can you suggest a better approach?

Comment: @sofiat123: No need. It is just my preference and not *better*. Just imagine your navi while driving.. *Follow the road for twenty miles* and suddenly after one mile *take the exit to the right at once*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the need for: `if (!str1) return true;`

It is a boundary case. It checks whether the first string is empty. One can ask: is an empty string always a subsequence of another string? The answer is: yes.

This statement could be made to look identical to the other `if` statement: `if (i === str1.length) return true;`. That would work also. And it demonstrates that actually it is performing the same test, but for the case where `i` is 0.

This statement would actually not be needed if the second string was guaranteed to not be empty, because in that case the loop would make its first iteration, and there the other `if` statement's condition would be true, and so the function would still return true. However if *both* strings are empty, the function should also return true, and that would not happen if you would not have this statement.

> I don't get this line either: `if (i===str1.length) return true;`

`i` represents the number of characters of `str1` that you have found in `str2` (in order). So if `i` equals the length of the first string, then you know that you have found all the characters of `str1`: so it makes no sense to still continue the loop as there is nothing else to find. So it is time to exit the function with a positive outcome.

#### Alternative

You could make the loop-condition include the *negation* of this "exit" condition, so that you don't need the `if` any more:

```
function isSubsequence(str1, str2) {
  let i = 0;
  // Continue as long as there are characters to compare...
  for (let j = 0; i < str1.length && j < str2.length; j++) {
    if (str2[j] === str1[i]) i++;
  }
  // Now return true if, and only when, all of str1 was found in str2
  return i === str1.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `if (!str1) return true;`

This statement returns true when the first string is an empty string. Because We can derive an empty string by removing all the characters of another string. That is why an empty string is a subsequence of any string. Unless it is mentioned explicitly that we are looking for a non-empty subsequence. [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence)

2. `if (i===str1.length) return true;`

While we are checking character equality of both the string, if we hit the end of the first string and all the previous characters were equal we can say that str1 is a subsequence of str2. We need to return from the function at this point, otherwise, you won't be able to find another character in str1. You can see the following example.

str1 = 'abc'.

str2 = 'abcdefg'.

i=0, j=0:

str1[i] = 'a'

str2[j] = 'a'

i=1, j=1:

str1[i] = 'b'

str2[j] = 'b'

i=2, j=2:

str1[i] = 'c'

str2[j] = 'c'

At this point we are at the end of str1. Now if we do not return then what will happen?

i=3, j=3

str1[3] = 'garbage values'

str2[3] = 'd'

They didn't match so we keep increasing the value of j but we won't be updating the value of i. Because of `if (str2[j] === str1[i]) i++;`. In that case we will loop through the str2 length and in the end we will return false. Which is a false result.